# How to plot a histogram with the yaxis as the "total of y values corresponding to each x bin" and x axis as n bins of x in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

Say I have two arrays:

```
x=np.random.uniform(0,10,100)
y=np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
```

I want to make n bins between xmin=0 and xmax=10. For each y, there is a corresponding x which belongs to one of these n bins. Say the value corresponding to each bin is initially zero. What I wish to do is add each value of y to its corresponding x's bin and plot a histogram with the x-axis as xmin to xmax with n bins and the y axis as the total of all y values added to corresponding x's bins. How can one do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i think its easier to use a bar plot instead of a histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xmax = 6600
xmin = 6400
x = np.random.uniform(xmin, xmax, 10000)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10000)
number_of_bins = 100

bins = [xmin]
step = (xmax - xmin)/number_of_bins
print("step = ", step)
for i in range(1, number_of_bins+1):
    bins.append(xmin + step*i)
print("bins = ", bins)

# time to create the sums for each bin
sums = [0] * number_of_bins

for i in range(len(x)):
    sums[int((x[i]-xmin)/step)] += y[i]
print(sums)

xbar = []
for i in range(number_of_bins):
 xbar.append(step/2 + xmin + step*i)
# now i have to create the x axis values for the barplot
plt.bar(xbar, sums, label="Bars")
plt.xlabel("X axis label")
plt.ylabel("Y axis label")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]   Here is the new result

If you don't understand something please tell me, in order to explain it

Comment: Thanks for the bar plot suggestion. But this won't work for say `xmax = 6600
xmin = 6400
x = np.random.uniform(xmin,xmax, 1000)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
number_of_bins = 100`

Clearly `bins.append(step*i)` has to be changed to `bins.append(xmin+step*i)`. 

`sums[int(x[i]/step)] += y[i]` is creating the problem. The logic of `int(x[i]/step)` is not for a general case.

Comment: @KJay you have a point, i see the problem. Can i ask you one more thing... When you make the x value like this: x=np.random.uniform(0,10,100), the values 0 and 10 represent the xmin and xmax?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Sorry if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: @KJay i did some minor changes. I think it is working as it should now. Tell me if i am missing somethink...

Comment: It is. Thank you!